# two .ASPXAuth cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have ported solution from vs2013 to 2015. My forms authentication is not working anymore.

On the first request I make user login and create cookie.
If I refresh page or click anywhere my ASPXAUTH cookie is not present anymore.

In chrome I can see that I have response cookie with the same name. Not sure why.

> Request Cookies                   613
>                  .ASPXAUTH  C83F564B3B0C929EA69218DC83C651DB2376C2541E9F83C4CD6FCB6B76570B68DD0DF1BB184531ACDABAA2F565C274D59B9958D372C4B927E2D34CD6D1337E26D82D346729DB2B60B263D51FF6BC1E5B464FDF5B32E003F9C963A7A5815D415C113C7A038D46FFD1441FE1F97F604CD1595BF4A430071BB4C47C8E18C4730E18BC827388    N/A N/A N/A 274
>   ASP.NET_SessionId 2pyvx1ia0rlsfymsmormbbcg    N/A N/A N/A 44
>              Response Cookies                   18               .ASPXAUTH          /   Session 18
>
> ---

The code I'm using to create auth cookie is:

```
Dim ticket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userName, Date.Now, Date.Now.AddMinutes(timeout), True, String.Empty)
Dim encTicket As String = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket)

Dim loginCookie As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName)
loginCookie.Value = encTicket
Response.Cookies.Add(loginCookie)
```

Is there any explanation to this behaviour? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that this is C# code? Why did you add C# tag?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you create ***FormsAuthenticationTicket*** manually.

In addition to the above code, you also need to retrieve the username from cookie on every request, and save it in ***IPrincipal*** Object, so that you can access ***User.Identity***.

### Global.asax.cs

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    private void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie decryptedCookie =
            Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket =
            FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(decryptedCookie.Value);

        var identity = new GenericIdentity(ticket.Name);
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);

        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
    }
}
```